# Is there a difference between relaying a transaction and relaying a block?

Tags: transactions, block, relay, message

I was checking the [message types](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Message_types) of the Bitcoin protocol and got curious whether there is a difference between relayin a transaction and a block, or not?

For example, *notfound* message say that `notfound is a response to a getdata, sent if any requested data items could not be relayed, for example, because the requested transaction was not in the memory pool or relay set.` Does it mean that `getdata` is only used for transactions?

Answer (score 2):

The wiki is terribly outdated, check out the Bitcoin developer guide instead:

> The response to a `getdata` message can be a `tx` message, `block` message, `merkleblock` message, or `notfound` message.

Source: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getdata